# How to add auto insert username & password on bat file?

Tags: batch-file, passwords, addition

I want to make a bat file that open a program and auto insert username & password automatically ..
the program is origin, located in here C:\Program Files (x86)\Origin\Origin.exe ..
please tell me how to do that ?

Comment: If you're looking to input text into a programs input box, you're better off using VBScript, as batch has no way of doing so.

Answer (score 6):

You could try something like this:

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
set "username=test"
set "password=1234"
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Origin\Origin.exe"
CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" "%username%{tab}%password%{enter}"
goto :EOF

@end

WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

This assumes the cursor is automatically in the first field, and there is 1 tab needed to go to the second field. It also presses enter automatically.

If this doesn't work because the program takes too long to start you can add a `timeout /t 5 /nobreak >nul` after the start line

Comment: I've got an error using .vbs like this
Line : 1
Char : 1
Error : Invalid character
Code : 800A0408
Source : Microsoft VBScript compilation error

Comment: @BillyAdelphia this is a hybrid batch script, you should save it as **.bat**, not .vbs. Also, make sure to save it as .ansi, when you save at the bottom right of the window.

Comment: This is really useful for testing purpose. I hated typing username & password every run. You have saved my time a lot.

Comment: @duong_dajgja if my answer solved your problem you should click the check to the left of it to accept it, so other people can see it too

Comment: @DennisvanGils Sorry... I am not the question owner :(

Comment: @duong_dajgja my bad, didn't realise that

Comment: Hi is this applicable to your own program?

Comment: @AyukNayr If you mean a program you made yourself, as long as the program starts with the field for your username selected, tab can be used to focus the password field and finally enter can be used to try and login it should work for any program.

Comment: yeah it did, I just mistype something. sorry for that :D